# Why do I not need to dereference a char pointer to output the c-style string?

Tags: c++, arrays, string, char

The following code will print out the string:

```
   char* test = "test";
   std::cout << test << std::endl;
```

Although I do get this compiler (GCC) warning:

> warning: deprecated conversion from string constant to 'char*'

Why do I not need to dereference the `char` pointer, to access the data? Also, why is what I have written deprecated, what should I use instead if I don't want a costly `std::string` object?

Comment: costly != constant, right? Nobody wants costly objects

Comment: As others said, you are putting a `const` string literal to a non-const pointer. Creating a non-const pointer from a const object is pretty much illegal, so this likely works because C doesn't have `const`, but string literals come from C.

Answer (score 2):

> Why do I not need to dereference the char pointer

Because the iostreams classes have an overload for `char*` / `char const*`. Dereferencing it would only output a single `char` anyway.

> Also, why is what I have written deprecated, what should I use instead
>   if I don't want a costly std::string object?

While it's *highly* unlikely using `std::string` will be detectibly "costly" in your program, you can change the type of `test` to `char const*`.

Comment: `char const*` ? Not `const char*` ?

Comment: @Geoffroy `const <type>` is an exception for line beginnings. `const` usually always refer to the preceding token.

Comment: @Quentin, okay thank you for you answer, I just never saw it like that!

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Although I take point with the "it's highly unlikely using std::string will be detectibly "costly" in your program". I am parsing a file and its much quicker to load all the chars in to a char array and use a start and end pointer to effectively "create" a string, than to keep creating string objects everywhere with lots of heap allocation.

Comment: @user997112 Measure first, speculate later. It's conceivable there will be a measurable difference, although it's highly unlikely it will be a *significant* difference, enough to forgo using something as useful as `std::string`.

Answer (score 2):

First off: the problem is in this line

```
char* test = "test";
```

a string literal is read-only data, so you should actually declare this as

```
const char* test = "test";
```

to make the compiler happy (i.e. *I promise I won't try to modify that data, I'll be punished with undefined behavior if I do*). That said, you don't need to dereference the pointer since there's a `const char*` [**overload**](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ostream/ostream/operator-free/) to use that data. And this also answers you to the costly point (unless you meant something else).